# How to launch python program at startup on Ubuntu 18.04 (Jetson TX2)?

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson

I have a python3 program that uses CUDA, CNNs, OpenCV, a USB camera,UART communication with an arduino... I would like to launch the program at startup of my jetson-TX2 ( using ubuntu 18.04) but I don't know how to do so.

I tried to add this command:  /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /home/nvidia/program.py" to the "Startup applications". ( the command works when running on terminal) But nothing shows up.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: study what is UNIX init and how to create a systemd service.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna wanna go to your handy dandy command line, and type "crontab -e"

It may ask you to select a text editor by entering a number. If it does, just pick whichever you prefer.  Scroll to the bottom of the file, and make a new line that says "@reboot python3 /path/to/script"